# Create a Grid inside a row from code behind - WPF

Tags: wpf, code-behind

I have a main Grid container in my XAML as follows.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid Name="mainGrid">
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And I need to get the following structure by adding controls to the 'mainGrid from code behind.[image]

Basically, it should be another grid inside the first row and it has two columns. Could anyone help me to achieve this?

I may use two Stack Panels for the first two rows but it should be a grid inside the first stack panel. How am I suppose to add my Grid Control to the Stack Panel which is created at the runtime?

```
Grid _grid = new Grid();
grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });

_grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
_grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition() { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
```

Comment: `mainGrid.Children.Add(_grid);` - This is however bad practice. Do not create UI elements in code. Use DataTemplates instead.

Comment: Thank you .yes, I know but the requirement is to create dynamic charts where users can click on a chart then drill down to another 2 levels and navigate between them back and forth.

Comment: If you know how to add one Panel to the Children collection of another Panel, i should be easy to add one more level.

Comment: Exactly and that is where I'm struggling at. 
Grid.SetRow(dataChart, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(dataChart, 0);
This is to add the chart to the Grid, but there is another Level lies outside of it.In here Grid is a static class.

Comment: You might be better off using an ItemsControl or ListView in the first row and make the ItemsPanel an UniformGrid with 1 Row and n Columns.

Comment: @LadderLogic: "How am I suppose to add my Grid Control to the Stack Panel which is created at the runtime?" `stackPanel.Children.Add(_grid);`? All `Panel` derived classes inherit the `Children` property.